# How to remember session when redirection occurs?

Tags: javascript, magento2, e2e-testing, cypress

I am using Cypress to test Mageto2.

Problem: Whenever I navigate to different parts of the back end I am requested to log in (And Magento redirects to a certain set page after login instead of the requested page)

Question: Is there a way to remember my session when testing with Cypress so I don't have to log in for any redirection to a part of the backed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress clears all cookies before each test

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: "adminhtml"
})
```

see: https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-preserve-cookies-localStorage-in-between-my-tests

fyi: **adminhtml** cookie stores admin's session id

**EDIT**

It appears that in magento 2 admin session id is stored in a cookie named "**admin**"

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: "admin"
})
```

Comment: you're welcome. don't forget to accept my answer and upvote ;)